# API REST java persistencia onetomany

Tags: java, json, api, hibernate, rest

Hola amigos nuevamente vuelvo a consultarles,y desde ya agradezco a quienes se tomaran el tiempo de responder y ayudarme. bueno soy nuevo en todo esto de java, les comento que estoy tratando de generar un api rest con dos tablas relacionadas, estoy ocupando netbeans  con maven y deployando en payara con una base de datos postgress alojada en heroku.

mi problema es que estoy obteniendo un java.lang.StackOverflowError 
solo estoy probando el metodo GET general o sea pretendo  que de arrastre me traiga todas las sucursales y empleados en un json  aca les dejo mi configuración

primero las persistencias 
empleado

```
package root.persistence.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
*
* @author rodrigo
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "empleados")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.id = :id")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByNombre", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.nombre = :nombre")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByApellido", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.apellido = :apellido")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByRut", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.rut = :rut")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByPuesto", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.puesto = :puesto")})
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "apellido")
private String apellido;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "rut")
private String rut;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "puesto")
private String puesto;
@JoinColumn(name = "idsucursal", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Sucursal idsucursal;

public Empleado() {
}

public Empleado(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getRut() {
    return rut;
}

public void setRut(String rut) {
    this.rut = rut;
}

public String getPuesto() {
    return puesto;
}

public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
    this.puesto = puesto;
}

public Sucursal getIdsucursal() {
    return idsucursal;
}

public void setIdsucursal(Sucursal idsucursal) {
    this.idsucursal = idsucursal;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Empleado)) {
        return false;
    }
    Empleado other = (Empleado) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "root.persistence.entities.Empleado[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

y ahora mi clase de persistencia Sucursal
    /*
    * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
   Properties.
    * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    * and open the template in the editor.
    */
   package root.persistence.entities;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
*
* @author rodrigo
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "sucursales")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.id = :id")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findByComuna", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.comuna = :comuna")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.direccion = :direccion")})
public class Sucursal implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "comuna")
private String comuna;
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "direccion")
private String direccion;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idsucursal", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Empleado> empleadoList;

public Sucursal() {
}

public Sucursal(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getComuna() {
    return comuna;
}

public void setComuna(String comuna) {
    this.comuna = comuna;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<Empleado> getEmpleadoList() {
    return empleadoList;
}

public void setEmpleadoList(List<Empleado> empleadoList) {
    this.empleadoList = empleadoList;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Sucursal)) {
        return false;
    }
    Sucursal other = (Sucursal) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "root.persistence.entities.Sucursal[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}
 my archivo POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>asucursalesrest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>asucursalesrest</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

tengo un punto de entrada a mi api 
APPconfig

```
package root.services;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;




@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AppConfig extends Application{

}
```

y una clase desde donde genero los metodos, hasta el momento solo hice el metodo get, ya que queria probar pero no me ha funcionado.. configure eager, porque en teoria deberia llamar a todos los hijos (empleados) de una sucursal.

```
package root.services;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import root.persistence.entities.Empleado;
import root.persistence.entities.Sucursal;

@Path("/sucursales")
public class SucursalesREST {

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UP_Sucursales");
EntityManager em;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listarTodo() {

    em = emf.createEntityManager();


List<Sucursal> lista = em.createNamedQuery("Sucursal.findAll").getResultList();

return Response.ok().entity(lista).build();
```

}
}
 pero al realizar las pruebas obtengo el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que quizas sea un error de principiantes, pues como les comente  soy nuevo en esto de java, y las  APIs y el uso de persistencias, ojala alguien peuda ayudarme ya que llevo dias con el mismo error, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo, creo que tu problema tiene que ver con que estas anotando la relación entre los empleados y las sucursales como EAGER en ambos lados de la relación. Al buscar las sucursales, estas traen a sus empleados y estos vuelven a traer a las sucursales, el ciclo continúa de forma indefinida hasta que te quedas sin memoria.

Yo te recomendaría usar EAGER en un único lado de la relación. Tené en cuenta que la relación `@ManyToOne` es EAGER por defecto asi que, si queres que la lista de empleados mantenga esta propiedad, vas a tener que definir explícitamente a la sucursal como LAZY.

Espero que esto te ayude  :)

Comment: No lo habia pensado voy a probar y comento

Comment: Perfecto, espero tu respuesta!

Comment: probe y se mantiene el mismo error deje la sucursal como lazy y empleados como eager

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idsucursal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: Ahora quizas para mi mejor entendimiento deberia dejar ambas comolazy y llamarlas desde mi controlador de servicio, ne ese caso como deberia ser la sintaxis del metodo?? ya que ahora lo tengo asi...

Comment: Path("/sucursales")
public class SucursalesREST {
    
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UP_Sucursales");
    EntityManager em;
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response listarTodo() {
  
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
      
    
    List<Sucursal> lista = em.createNamedQuery("Sucursal.findAll").getResultList();
      
    return Response.ok().entity(lista).build();
    
    
}
}

Comment: Solo para estar seguro, en qué linea de codigo aparece la excepción?

Comment: Lo solucione, guardando el resultado de la consulta en un string  y convirtiendo este string a json.

Comment: Entiendo que soluciona tu problema, pero me parecería mejor si resolvemos tu problema de la forma correcta asi evitamos que te suceda otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle solución al problema agregando esta etiqueta @JasonbTransient junto a la etiqueta de @XMLTransient  en getListEmpleados() esto evitara que te de el error de stackoverflow ya que se esta generando un ciclo recursivo infinito..de acuerdo a lo que menciona la respuesta de Ariel, el problema de utilizar esta anotación es que ya no podras acceder directamente a la lista de empleados de la sucursal debido a q esta anotación @JasonbTransient lo que hace es evitar que se persistan estos datos. Aun sigo buscando alguna otra solucion para evitar el ciclo recursivo.. si tiene una mejor solución me la comentas

Comment: Anteriormente ya habias colocado una respuesta la cual no tiene nada que ver con la solucion del problema (que todavia no se porque no se ha eliminado, [ver respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/251473/107347)) y ahora colocas esta respuesta, lo mejor hubiera sido que editaras la anterior respuesta. Adicional esta respuesta mas que aportar una solucion es un comentario extensamente largo.